Advanced Filtering in Kendo Spreadsheet (Jquery)
In a Kendo UI Spreadsheet implemented using jQuery, there is a requirement to filter data within a specific column based on certain values. The column to be filtered contains a mix of label rows and data rows. The challenge is to apply the filter exclusively to the data rows while excluding the label rows from being filtered. This is necessary because the label rows contain text headers or other non-data information that should remain visible regardless of the filter applied. For instance, label rows might contain non-empty strings that serve as headers, while data rows contain numeric or specific text values that need to be filtered. The goal is to target only the data rows, ensuring that the labels are preserved and the data is accurately filtered according to the specified criteria.
I only tryed searching around the documentation but to me it doesnt seem possible
